# Create instance of Firefox or chrome in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, firefox

I can create IE instance in C#

```
// start the browser
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer m_IExplorer = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();


// go to home page
m_WebBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)m_IExplorer;
```

and works in its events like
BeforeNavigate
DownloadBegin

---

can I do this and work in this events in Firefox or chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can start a process of the browser you want:

```
Process.Start(@"%AppData%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "url");
```

You have no access to events though.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.